# When I press the register or the login button it does nothing... I am doing this with ASP.NET Core MVC and I don't know what's wrong with this

Tags: c#, html, authentication, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I create this project for ASP.NET Core MVC and I did everything and now I was working on the log in and register but when I did it and launch the project it didn't work... well, at least I can't test it because when I press the register ou login anchor it sends me to nowhere.

`_layout`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - DWeb_MVC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DWeb_MVC.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">DWeb_MVC</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - DWeb_MVC - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

`Login.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe" class="form-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to log in.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins!)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

`login.cshtml.cs`:

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DWeb_MVC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

---register.cshtml---

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">

    <input asp-for="Input.Clientes.Email" value="a@gmail.com" type="hidden" />

    <div class="row">
        <hr />

        <div class="col-md-6">
            
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email">Email</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password">Password</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Clientes.Nome" class="form-control" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Clientes.Nome"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Clientes.Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Clientes.Telemovel" class="form-control" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Clientes.Telemovel"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Clientes.Telemovel" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Clientes.Morada" class="form-control" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Clientes.Morada"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Clientes.Morada" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Clientes.CodPostal" class="form-control" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Clientes.CodPostal"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Clientes.CodPostal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

---register.cshtml.cs---

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DWeb_MVC.Data;
using DWeb_MVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DWeb_MVC.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IUserStore<IdentityUser> userStore,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// atributo para recolher os dados do Criador
            /// </summary>
            public Clientes Clientes { get; set; }
        }


        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            //ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

                //criaçao do user
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                //se houver sucesso
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    //adicionar os dados do "cliente" (funcionário) à BD
                    
                    Input.Clientes.Email = Input.Email; 
                    Input.Clientes.UserId = user.Id;

                    // adicionar os dados à BD
                    try
                    {
                        _context.Add(Input.Clientes);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // não esquecer tratar da exceção
                        // por exemplo, apagar o USER, se não se consegue 
                        // criar o CRIADOR
                        throw;
                    }

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private IdentityUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<IdentityUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(IdentityUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(IdentityUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }

        private IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> GetEmailStore()
        {
            if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
            }
            return (IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser>)_userStore;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you filter this a bit, reduce the post down to the relevant bits of code, rather than including everything you've got - doing so will make it easier for the rest of us to parse and help you, and also might help you identify the issue in the process ;)

Comment: Can you also check your browser's developer console for any errors?

Comment: My recomendation is use AJAX post to call some ActionResult Method and use diferents Methods tu manage your actions on your controller. :)

Comment: Looks like you are using asp.net core default indentity. So you can use scaffolding. Just right click on the `Area` folder and click Add new scaffolded item, then choose `Identity`.  I trust using scaffolded item should work for you.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCmIl.png